# merge csv files in unix, bash

Tags: bash, csv, unix, merge

I have a few csv files that are formatted like:

test1.csv:

```
    field,port1
    a1,0.2
    a2,0.3
    a3,0.6
```

test2.csv:

```
field,port2
b1,0.5
b2,0.6
b3,0.7
b4,0.1
b5,0.5
```

test3.csv:

```
field, port3
c1,0.1
c2,0.4
```

and so forth.I want to merge these csvs into a single so it would look like:

```
field,port1,field,port2,field,port3
a1,0.2,b1,0.5,c1,0.1
a2,0.3,b2,0.6,c2,0.4
a3,0.6,b3,0.7,,
,,b4,0.1,,
,,b5,0.5,,
```

how can I do this? I cat >> but that would but everything in the first two columns.  I can go about that way if I have to but having a merge like this can make my life a lot simpler.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on fedorqui's answer:

```
paste -d: test[1-3].csv | sed -e's/^:/,:/' -e's/::/:,:/g' -e's/::/:,:/g' -e's/:$/:,/' -e's/:/,/g'
```

(assuming you have no `:` in your files - but you can choose another temporary separator)

This restores all the commas you expect. The pair of identical substitution instructions is needed because a substituted string is not taken into account for another substitution.

In general:

```
paste -d'T' file... | sed -e's/^T/ET/' -e's/TT/TET/g' -e's/TT/TET/g' -e's/T$/TE/' -e's/T/S/g'
```

where `T` is the temporary separator (`:` above), `E` is the string that should replace an empty or missing line (`,` above), and `S` is the separator between the lines of the `paste`d files (`,` above). The temporary separator `T` (a generic string) must not appear in the files and in `E`, while the final separator `S` can.

Warning: The above commands *may* need spaces before the quoted strings in your shell

Comment: I get an error sed: Unrecognized command: -es/::/:,:/g. Can you help?

Comment: @yatici: try adding a space after -e (that is not necessary, because of the single quotes, in bash, but might be necessary in other shells)

Comment: yep seems like it works. I am on bash too. Maybe just a different version issue.

Comment: @yatici, I have tried on bash 4.1.5 and bash 4.1.10, no space needed - funny

Answer (score 4):

`paste` can do quite a similar thing:

```
$ paste -d, test[1-3].csv
field,port1,field,port2,field, port3
a1,0.2,b1,0.5,c1,0.1
a2,0.3,b2,0.6,c2,0.4
a3,0.6,b3,0.7,
,b4,0.1,
,b5,0.5,
```

Note that `-d,` stands for delimiter to be a comma.

Comment: hmm didn't know there was a paste command. This makes things easier.

Comment: yea I lose commas with this and order shifts

Comment: @glennjackman that is not enough: it does't solve the case when there is a shorter file between two longer ones. See my answer for the solution