# Merge two csv files in bash

Tags: bash

I have two csv files.

**Columns of the first file**

```
col1, col2, col3,......col4095, col4096, col4097
```

**Columns of the second file**

```
col1, col2, col3,......,col4095, col4096, col4097
```

**Expected output - the last column of the first file is discarded**

```
col1, col2, col3.......,col4095. col4096, col1, col2, col3....col4095, col4096, col4097
```

Both files have the same number of rows, I want to merge the two files into one file.

Comment: i would use "q" for this. http://harelba.github.io/q/

Comment: related: [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833187/merge-csv-files-in-unix-bash) and [append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641948/merging-csv-files-appending-instead-of-merging)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `paste` :

```
paste -d, f1.csv f2.csv > out.csv
```

To ignore last column of first file:

```
awk -F, 'NF-=1' OFS=, f1.csv | paste -d, - f2.csv > out.csv
```

Comment: I don''t need last column of first file, @sat

Comment: @cpwah, Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With only `awk`:

```
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) out=out$i", " ; next} \
                        {out=out$0} END{print out}' f1.csv f2.csv
```

- `-F ',[[:blank:]]*'` sets the field separator as `,` followed by any number of space/tab
- `NR==FNR` will be true for the first file only, then `{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) out=out$i", " ; next}` will be executed, which will iterate over, and concatenate all the fields but the last one in variable `out`
- The record of the second file would be concatenated to the variable `out` -- `{out=out$0}`
- Finally, the value of variable `out` is printed -- `END{print out}`

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.csv                                                                                                        
col1, col2, col3,......col4095, col4096, col4097

% cat f2.csv 
col1, col2, col3,......,col4095, col4096, col4097

% awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) out=out$i", " ; next} {out=out$0} END{print out}' f1.csv f2.csv 
col1, col2, col3, ......col4095, col4096, col1, col2, col3,......,col4095, col4096, col4097
```